# Hide time/date display on login screen

Tags: pantheon

from some digging I understand by default Elementary OS uses pantheon-greeter which uses LightDM.

Is there a way to hide the time and date display on the login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the time and date are hardcoded into the greeter

Comment: Too bad, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you feel like getting dirty with code, you can remove it yourself as it's actually pretty straightforward (it only took me 25 min because I didn't realize we can [ignore a libmutter dependency message](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93#issuecomment-561520718))

assuming you have git setup, clone the greeter component:

```
git clone https://github.com/elementary/greeter
```

as of 5.1 (Hera), comment out in src/Widgets/DataTimeWidget.vala:

```
//        add (time_label);
//        add (date_label);
```

follow these [instructions to compile and install changes to Elementary](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/23914/20912).

now your flow is no longer interrupted by time staring you in the face :)